# Смена картинки imageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

Как можно сменить картинку, которая есть в ресурсах. В ресурсах нет `imageName`, а есть картинки `p1`, `p2` ,`p3`,.. и т.д. Нужно, чтобы каждый раз показывались разные картинки в зависимости от position

```
String imageName = ("p"+position);
imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.imageName);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно получить идентификатор ресурса по его имени:

```
String mDrawableName = "p" + position;
int resID = imageView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", imageView.getContext().getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(resID);
```

Comment: У меня context красным подсвечивает.

Comment: @Vladoo7, естественно. Вам нужно подставить на его место переменную типа `Context`. Если вы работаете в адаптере, то у адаптера есть метод `getContext();`

Comment: @Vladoo7, я отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помоголо

Comment: @Vladoo7, если помогло, то отметьте ответ, как правильный